# How to convert BC dates in NodaTime Instant to a regular date

Tags: nodatime

`Instant.FromUnixTimeSeconds(-100100000000).ToDateTimeUtc1`

Once the date gets too ancient this doesn't work anymore, for example, BC dates.

Is there any easy way to convert NodaTime instant values to years months days, that works for the entire range of supported Instant values (aka 27000 BCE to 31000 CE) ?

I don't mind what data type, I am just looking to easily extract the regular time periods from the Instant values.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "doesn't work anymore" - noting that `DateTime.MinValue` is 0001-01-01. Also note that Noda Time hasn't supported 27000BCE to 31000CE for a long time - see https://nodatime.org/3.1.x/userguide/range

Answer (score 1):

It's been a year or more since I've used Nodatime, but [this page in the user guide][1] says

> Additionally, all calendars are restricted to four digit formats, even
> in year-of-era representations, which avoids ever having to parse
> 5-digit years. This leads to a Gregorian calendar from 9999 BCE to
> 9999 CE inclusive, or -9998 to 9999 in "absolute" years.

You're question could be read to mean you didn't think BC dates worked at all. When you get more than a few thousand years from the present, strange things start to happen, such as the changing rotation rate of the Earth means there are different kinds of days; those that would be counted from sunrises vs. the kind of time used in radioactive decay, or calculation of planetary positions. It might be helpful if you mentioned your application.
[1]: https://nodatime.org/3.1.x/userguide/range